# How to Get columns Records with days between two dates in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `partywise_account_ledger` with columns `name_of_the_customer`, `invoice_date` and `invoice_value`. I want to retrieve the `invoice_value` depending on number of days. To get the value for `< 5 days` I use the query:

```
select name_of_the_customer, sum(invoice_value)
from partywise_accounts_ledger
where datediff(d, invoice_date, '2017-04-19') < 5
group by name_of_the_customer
```

[This is the Result of the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQB57.png)

How can I get the `< 10 days` column appended to it and show in single statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to conditional aggregation:

```
select name_of_the_customer,
       sum(case when datediff(d, invoice_date, '2017-04-19') < 5 then invoice_value end),
       sum(case when datediff(d, invoice_date, '2017-04-19') < 10 then invoice_value end)
from partywise_accounts_ledger
where datediff(d, invoice_date, '2017-04-19') < 10
group by name_of_the_customer
```

The second `SUM()` (for < 10 days), can be simplifed as `sum(invoice_value)`.